# Is it possible to use string from a text file as java code

Tags: java, string

lets say i have written "doSomthing()" in a text file. Does anybody know if it is possible to have that text doSomthing() without having to wirite:

```
if(txt.equals("doSomthing()"){ 
    doSomthing();
}
```

Comment: The actual answer to your question is yes. If you want to know how look at the chapter named `Reflexion`in the java tutorial.

Comment: "*[...] possible to have that text doSomthing() without having to wirite [...]*" - What do you mean by this? Do you mean you have an implementation of that method in said txt-file and you want to "run" the code in the txt-file?

Comment: You *could* use reflection, but you shouldn’t.  A better approach is an EnumMap whose values are Runnables (or Callables, Functions, Consumers, etc.).

Comment: What's wrong with using it in the way you have displayed?

Comment: Thanx for your answers. to clarify i will have lots of different functions and the text file will "decide" what should be done. also the text file could have multiple functions in it and it should be done in the same order as it come.

Comment: i will look into reflexion and enumMap. thanx again for your answers

Answer (score 0):

the answer was indeed in the reflection chapter and it's straight forward. thanx for that StephaneM :

Method method = MyClass.class.getMethod("doSometing", String.Object);
Object returnValue = method.invoke(null, "parameter-value1");